# how to upload both image and video at the same time with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i'm trying to upload image and video at the same time but couldn't

i've tried this but it seems to not work, the image file will upload successfully but the video won't

```
$request->validate([
        'title'=> 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
        'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4'
    ]);

    $film= Film::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => Str::slug($request->title),
        'description' => $request->description,
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);

    $file = new Film();

    if($request->file('file')) {
            $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file_path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $file_name, 'public');

            $file->name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->file = '/storage/' . $file_path;
            $film->update(['file' => $file_name]);
            $film->update(['path' => $file_path]);

            return response()->json(['success'=>'File uploaded successfully.']);
    }
    if ($request->file('video')){
            $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file_path = $request->file('video')->storeAs('uploads', $file_name, 'public');

            $file->name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->file = '/storage/' . $file_path;
            $film->update(['video' => $file_name]);
            $film->update(['videoPath' => $file_path]);

            return response()->json(['success'=>'File uploaded successfully.']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are returning a response after you process the image file so the condition for the video can't be reached. If you want to process both just return after all the operations are done.

```
$request->validate([
    'title'=> 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048',
    'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4'
]);

$film= Film::create([
    'title' => $request->title,
    'slug' => Str::slug($request->title),
    'description' => $request->description,
    'user_id' => auth()->id()
]);

if($request->file('file')) {
    $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file_path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $file_name, 'public');

    $film->update([
        'file' => $file_name,
        'path' => $file_path
    ]);
}

if ($request->file('video')){
    $file_name = time().'_'.$request->video->getClientOriginalName();
    $file_path = $request->file('video')->storeAs('uploads', $file_name, 'public');

    $film->update([
        'video' => $file_name,
        'videoPath' => $file_path
    ]);
}

return response()->json(['success'=>'Files uploaded successfully.']);
```

You can also add additional checks if the files inside each condition is processed successfully.

The `$file` variable is unnecessary and it's not even saved so that can be removed as well.

As for the reason it's uploading twice, you are calling `->file` again inside the `video` condition which should be `->video`.

And as an aside, you can update multiple fields at once by passing multiple array items instead of calling update for each property which can save you db requests.

Answer (score 0):

jech chua, thanks it worked but it uploads the image twice.

maybe there a problem in my blade

```
<form action="/film" class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="f">
            <div class="sect1">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="title" placeholder="Title..">
                <textarea name="description" class="textarea" placeholder="Description.."></textarea>
                <h2>Upload image</h2><input type="file" name="file" class="file">
            </div>
            <div class="dropz" id="image-upload">
                <h2>Upload video</h2>
                <input type="file" name="video">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="buttn">Create film</button>
    </form>
```